# (Generalized) Jarzynski equality

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, quantum-information, information

Sagawa and Ueda [ref](https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.4914), generalized the [Jarzynski equality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jarzynski_equality) in the presence of a feedback control, leading to the following equation:

$$  \langle e^{-\beta(W-\Delta F)-I} \rangle = 1.$$

Can I interpret and use this equation when the mutual information is between two systems and not representing the information learned from the feedback control?